# Multi tablePanel with radioButtons in them do not switch output

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, radio-button

I'm trying to create a Shiny app who takes a precise kind of csv, make some calculations with another two scripts call engine.R and sequenzaGiorni.R (in which there's only a date function), and return a list o dataframe. What I would like to have is a page with tabPanels on the right with radioButtons because, for 6 of 7 topics, I need to show alternatively two different tables.

This is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

# Carico la funzione giorniMese

source("sequenzaGiorni.R")


# DEFINIZIONE DELL'INTERFACCIA UTENTE -------------------------------------


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    style = "background-color: #000000; padding: 10px; text-align: center;",
    tags$img(src = "bannerHeader2.png", width = "1800px", height = "710px")
  ),
  titlePanel(h1("Modello di influenza per il Gruppo FNM",
                style='text-align: center;
                font-family:Poppins;
                     padding-left: 15px')),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", h3("Carica il file di dati di Blogmeter (CSV)",
                           style='font-family:Poppins;
                           font-size:16px'), buttonLabel = "CERCA..."),
      checkboxInput("header", p("Il file ha l'intestazione?",
                                style='font-family:Poppins;
                           font-size:14px'), value = TRUE),
      uiOutput("avviamiento"),
      # actionButton("calculate", "Avvia"),
      uiOutput("scaricamiento"),
      style = 'border-radius:0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    min-height:600px'),
    
    mainPanel(
      
  # CREAZIONE DELLE LINGUETTE DELLE VARIE SEZIONI ---------------------------
      
      tabsetPanel(id = "pannello",
                  tabPanel(p("Risultati complessivi",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                           font-size:14px'),
                           uiOutput("Complessivi")),
                  tabPanel(p("Cittadinanza",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("CittBivio")),
                  tabPanel(p("Visione",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("VisioBivio")),
                  
                  tabPanel(p("Performance",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("PerfoBivio")),
                  
                  tabPanel(p("Prodotti e servizi",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("ProdBivio")),
                  
                  tabPanel(p("Corporate Governance",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("CorBivio")),
                  
                  tabPanel(p("Lavoro",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("LavBivio")),
                  
                  tabPanel(p("Innovazione",
                             style='font-family:Poppins;
                          font-size:14px'), 
                           uiOutput("InnovBivio"))
      ),
      
      
  # IDENTIFICAZIONE DELLE TABELLE DA VISUALIZZARE ALLA FINE -----------------
      
      
      tableOutput("risultatiComplessivi"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiCittadinanza"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiLeadership"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiPerformance"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiProdServ"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiCorGov"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiLavoro"),
      tableOutput("RisultatiInnovazione")
    )
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('Complessivi')",
    #   tableOutput("risultatiComplessivi")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('CittBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiCittadinanza")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('VisioBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiLeadership")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('PerfoBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiPerformance")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('ProdBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiProdServ")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('CorBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiCorGov")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('LavBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiLavoro")),
    # conditionalPanel(
    #   condition = "$('.tab-link-active').hasClass('InnovBivio')",
    #   tableOutput("RisultatiInnovazione"))
    # 
  )
)


# DEFINIZIONE DELLA LOGICA DELL'APPLICAZIONE ------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # sel_citt <- reactive({input$CittBivio})
  # sel_visio <- reactive({input$VisioBivio})
  # sel_perfo <- reactive({input$PerfoBivio})
  # sel_prod <- reactive({input$ProdBivio})
  # sel_cor <- reactive({input$CorBivio})
  # sel_lav <- reactive({input$LavBivio})
  # sel_innov <- reactive({input$InnovBivio})
  # 
  # GENERAZIONE DEI PASSAGGI DOPO IL CARICAMENTO DEL FILE -------------------
  
  
  {
    # Esecuzione dei calcoli con il tasto Avvia
    
    output$avviamiento <- renderUI({
      req(input$file)
      actionButton("calculate", style = 'background-color: #5fab97;
                            width = 100
                            padding: 15px 32px;
                            color:white;
                            font-family:Poppins;
                            font-size:16px;', "AVVIA")
    })
  }
  
  {
    # Esecuzione dei calcoli
    calculatedData <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {
      # Esegui qui i tuoi calcoli sulla tibble 'data()'
      source("engine.R", local = TRUE)
      calculated <- tutto
      
      return(calculated)
    })
  }
  
  
  
  # CREAZIONE TABELLA RISULTATI COMPLESSIVI ---------------------------------
  
  # Sotto-dataset: Risultati complessivi
  output$Complessivi <- renderTable({
    req(input$calculate)
    calculatedData()[[1]]
  })
  
  
  # EVOCAZIONE radioButton() ------------------------------------------------
  
  # Cittadinanza 
  
  output$CittBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioCitt", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris1",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol1"),
                 selected = "Vol1")
  })
  
  # Visione e Leadership
  
  output$VisioBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioVisio", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris2",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol2"),
                 selected = "Vol2")
  })
  
  # Performance finanziaria
  
  output$PerfoBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioPerfo", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris3",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol3"),
                 selected = "Vol3")
  })
  
  # Prodotti e servizi
  
  output$ProdBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioProd", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris4",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol4"),
                 selected = "Vol4")
  })
  
  # Corporate Governance
  
  output$CorBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioCor", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris5",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol5"),
                 selected = "Vol5")
  })
  
  # Lavoro
  
  output$LavBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioLav", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris6",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol6"),
                 selected = "Vol6")
  })
  
  # Innovazione
  
  output$InnovBivio <- renderUI({
    req(input$calculate)
    radioButtons(inputId = "BivioInnov", label = "Cosa vuoi vedere?",
                 choices = c("Risultati" = "ris7",
                             "Volumi" = "Vol7"),
                 selected = "Vol7")
  })
  
  
  # VISUALIZZAZIONE TABELLE A SECONDA DELLA SEZIONE ATTIVATA ----------------
  
  
  # Cittadinanza 
  
  output$RisultatiCittadinanza <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioCitt)
    switch(input$BivioCitt,
           "ris1" = calculatedData()[[2]],
           "Vol1" = calculatedData()[[9]])
  })
  
  
  # Visione e Leadership
  
  output$RisultatiLeadership <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioVisio)
    switch(input$BivioVisio,
           "ris2" = calculatedData()[[6]],
           "Vol2" = calculatedData()[[13]])
  })
  
  # Performance finanziaria
  
  output$RisultatiPerformance <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioPerfo)
    switch(input$BivioPerfo,
           "ris3" = calculatedData()[[7]],
           "Vol3" = calculatedData()[[14]])
  })
  
  # Prodotti e servizi
  
  output$RisultatiProdServ <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioProd)
    switch(input$BivioProd,
           "ris4" = calculatedData()[[8]],
           "Vol4" = calculatedData()[[15]])
  })
  
  
  # Corporate Governance
  
  output$RisultatiCorGov <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioCor)
    switch(input$BivioCor,
           "ris5" = calculatedData()[[3]],
           "Vol5" = calculatedData()[[10]])
  })
  
  
  # Lavoro
  
  output$RisultatiLavoro <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioLav)
    switch(input$BivioLav,
           "ris6" = calculatedData()[[5]],
           "Vol6" = calculatedData()[[12]])
  })
  
  
  # Innovazione
  
  output$RisultatiInnovazione <- renderTable({
    req(input$BivioInnov)
    switch(input$BivioInnov,
           "ris7" = calculatedData()[[4]],
           "Vol7" = calculatedData()[[11]])
  })
  
  
  # Tasto Scarica risultati
  
  output$scaricamiento <- renderUI({
    req(input$file, calculatedData())
    downloadButton("scarica", style = 'background-color: #5fab97;
                            width = 100
                            padding: 15px 32px;
                            color:white;
                            font-family:Poppins;
                            font-size:16px',
                   "SCARICA I RISULTATI")
  })
  
  
  output$scarica <- downloadHandler(filename = "Risultati.xlsx",
                                    content = function(file) {
                                      writexl::write_xlsx(calculatedData(), file)
                                    })
  
  
  # # CANCELLA LE ALTRE TABELLE QUANDO SELEZIONO UNA TAB (non funziona) -------


 }

# LANCIO APPLICAZIONE -----------------------------------------------------

# Esecuzione dell'applicazione
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now it works in calculation and showing data, but when I click on a tabPanel that actually has radioButtons, its data doesn't disappear and, if I click them all, I see sequently all the the selections I've made for each tablePanel. I need to see a single table every time I choice a tab

Can anybody help me?